# How to change font size using an OpenXmlAttribute?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I want to change the fontsize in OpenXml for Excel using an OpenXmlAttribute("s", null, "1")) for example (in this case it sets the style to bold). I however can't find good documentation on all available arguments for the OpenXmlAttribute.

An example of my code would be

```
oxw = new OpenXmlWriter();
oxa = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
//This sets the data type to string
oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "str"));
//This sets the font style to bold. 0 is default and 1 is bold.
oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("s", null, "1"));
oxw.WriteStartElement(new Cell(), oxa);
oxw.WriteElement(new CellValue(string.Format("{0}", criteria.Title.ToString())));
oxw.WriteEndElement();
```

So is there something in the line of `OpenXmlAttribute("size", null, "48")`?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
By creating a stylesheet I can make my own custom OpenXmlAttribute arguments, so I would 1st create a Font, then a font style if I want it for example bold, append it to that font, and then append that font to a Fonts object. Then create a cell format, add the fontId to it, then append that cellformat object to a cellformats object.

```
Font font0 = new Font();         // Default font
Font font1 = new Font();         // Title font

Bold bold = new Bold();
font1.Append(bold);

FontSize fontSizeSearchTitle = new FontSize() { Val = 36 };
font1.Append(fontSizeTitle);

Fonts fonts = new Fonts();      // <APENDING Fonts>
fonts.Append(font0);
fonts.Append(font1);

CellFormat cellformat0 = new CellFormat() { FontId = 0, FillId = 0, BorderId = 0 }; // Default style : Mandatory | Style ID =0
CellFormat cellformat1 = new CellFormat() { FontId = 1 };  // Style with Bold text ; Style ID = 1

// <APENDING CellFormats>
CellFormats cellformats = new CellFormats();
cellformats.Append(cellformat0);
cellformats.Append(cellformat1);
```

And then I'll apply it to a cell using

```
                        //Write title
                        oxa = new List<OpenXmlAttribute>();
                        oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("t", null, "str"));
                        oxa.Add(new OpenXmlAttribute("s", null, "1"));
                        oxw.WriteStartElement(new Cell(), oxa);
                        oxw.WriteElement(new CellValue(string.Format("{0}", criteria.Title.ToString())));
                        oxw.WriteEndElement();
```